# How to get count of posts assigned to given category?

Tags: wp-query, categories

I have the following code to count the number of posts in a specific category. Based on the number of posts that it returns it should do something.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => '9',
);

$count_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = $count_query->post_count;

if ( $count >= 3) {

// do something     

}
```

This code works but only if I include `posts_per_page` in my array. Can someone explain me why this is?

I expected the code to work without the `post_per_page` as well. Instead it returns a 0 as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... It's pretty easy to explain...

### Problem explanation

Your code doesn't count anything - it retrieves posts that matches given query (you query posts that are in category with ID 9). If you provide no `posts_per_page` param, then default value is used (the one that is set in Settings). On the other hand, if you set `posts_per_page` to `-1`, then you'll get all posts that matches given query. But doing so is very bad idea - if there are thousands of posts, then you'll retrieve all of them from DB just to count them.

### Solution

One way to fix this would be to check `found_posts` instead of `post_count`. First one is "The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters" and the second one "The number of posts being displayed".

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => 9,
);

$count_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = $count_query->found_posts;

if ( $count >= 3) {
    // do something
}
```

### Better solution

But... There is much more efficient way to get count of posts in given category...

```
$category = get_category( 9 );  // <- change the ID of category

if ( $category->category_count >= 3 ) {
    // do something
}
```

Of course you should also check if the given category exists and so on.

Comment: Thanks @krzysiek-dróżdż ! That's an a very detailed and helpful explanation. Much appreciated :-)